# Integrate Twitter4j v3.0.3 to android application - Get TimeLine and Post Tweet [Working]

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

Android 2.3.3

Important Note ::: I am very new to integrating twitter and facebook stuff. I had a requirement of integrating new twitter4j to my application and stumbled on few examples to work out my way. My requirement was to get the tweets from the timeline. However, the example below also contains how to update the tweet from the application.

Note 2 ::: I have used the examples from [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-twitter-oauth-connect-tutorial/) and [here](https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/blob/master/twitter4j-examples/src/main/java/twitter4j/examples/timeline/GetHomeTimeline.java). All credit goes to the guys of these sites. I made a couple of changes and it worked.

The code is pretty much self explanatory and if you need any other clarifications, please visit the sites above.

---

Here is what I have done:

1. Signed up for Dev account at Twitter and got "consumer key" and "consumer secret". Replace them where ever you find the constants for consumer key and consumer secret in the code.
2. Downloaded twitter4j-3.0.3.zip from [here](http://twitter4j.org/en/)
3. Extracted the zip file and added the libraries from twitter-3.0.3->lib. I have added all the libraries as I was testing out the integration. You may want to add libraries that are needed for you.
4. Right Click on the project-> Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries->Add Jars. Go to lib folder in the project and add all libraries.

---

Please follow these steps and you will have the application integrated with twitter.

For posting tweet on twitter using the application, I have used the example from [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-twitter-oauth-connect-tutorial/).
For getting the timeline from twitter, I have used the example from [here](https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/blob/master/twitter4j-examples/src/main/java/twitter4j/examples/timeline/GetHomeTimeline.java).

---

Code:

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.twitt4jintegrationdemo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <!-- Permission - Internet Connect -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- Network State Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.twitt4jintegrationdemo.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="t4jsample"
                    android:scheme="oauth" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

ConnectionDetector.java

```
package com.example.twitt4jintegrationdemo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;

public class ConnectionDetector {

    private Context _context;

    public ConnectionDetector(Context context){
        this._context = context;
    }

    /**
     * Checking for all possible internet providers
     * **/
    public boolean isConnectingToInternet(){
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
          if (connectivity != null)
          {
              NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
              if (info != null)
                  for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                      if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                      {
                          return true;
                      }

          }
          return false;
    }
}
```

AlertDialogManager.java

```
package com.example.twitt4jintegrationdemo;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;

public class AlertDialogManager {
    /**
     * Function to display simple Alert Dialog
     * 
     * @param context
     *            - application context
     * @param title
     *            - alert dialog title
     * @param message
     *            - alert message
     * @param status
     *            - success/failure (used to set icon) - pass null if you don't
     *            want icon
     * */

    public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message,
            Boolean status) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle(title);

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage(message);

        if (status != null)

            // Setting OK Button
            alertDialog.setButton(0, "OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    });

        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.twitt4jintegrationdemo;

import java.util.List;

import com.example.twitt4jintegrationdemo.R;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.User;
import twitter4j.auth.AccessToken;
import twitter4j.auth.RequestToken;
import twitter4j.conf.Configuration;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // Constants
    /**
     * Register your here app https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new and get your
     * consumer key and secret
     * */
    static String TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = "o4YaT3H0SgmjQFSkGJy1A";
    static String TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET = "uxCIVsaPSsvckIBpSfZCLYGli0jHus4xMkE5sgk";

    // Preference Constants
    static String PREFERENCE_NAME = "twitter_oauth";
    static final String PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN = "oauth_token";
    static final String PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET = "oauth_token_secret";
    static final String PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN = "isTwitterLogedIn";

    static final String TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL = "oauth://t4jsample";

    // Twitter oauth urls
    static final String URL_TWITTER_AUTH = "auth_url";
    static final String URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER = "oauth_verifier";
    static final String URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_TOKEN = "oauth_token";

    // Login button
    Button btnLoginTwitter;
    // Update status button
    Button btnUpdateStatus;

    Button btnGetTimeLine;

    // Logout button
    Button btnLogoutTwitter;
    // EditText for update
    EditText txtUpdate;
    // lbl update
    TextView lblUpdate;
    TextView lblUserName;

    // Progress dialog
    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Twitter
    private static Twitter twitter;
    private static RequestToken requestToken;

    // Shared Preferences
    private static SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;

    // Internet Connection detector
    private ConnectionDetector cd;

    // Alert Dialog Manager
    AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

        // Check if Internet present
        if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
            // Internet Connection is not present
            alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this,
                    "Internet Connection Error",
                    "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
            // stop executing code by return
            return;
        }

        // Check if twitter keys are set
        if (TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY.trim().length() == 0
                || TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET.trim().length() == 0) {
            // Internet Connection is not present
            alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Twitter oAuth tokens",
                    "Please set your twitter oauth tokens first!", false);
            // stop executing code by return
            return;
        }

        // All UI elements
        btnLoginTwitter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLoginTwitter);
        btnUpdateStatus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUpdateStatus);

        btnGetTimeLine = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGetTimeLine);

        btnLogoutTwitter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogoutTwitter);
        txtUpdate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUpdateStatus);
        lblUpdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblUpdate);
        lblUserName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblUserName);

        // Shared Preferences
        mSharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
                "MyPref", 0);

        /**
         * Twitter login button click event will call loginToTwitter() function
         * */
        btnLoginTwitter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Call login twitter function
                loginToTwitter();
            }
        });

        /**
         * Button click event to Update Status, will call updateTwitterStatus()
         * function
         * */
        btnUpdateStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Call update status function
                // Get the status from EditText
                String status = txtUpdate.getText().toString();

                // Check for blank text
                if (status.trim().length() > 0) {
                    // update status
                    new updateTwitterStatus().execute(status);
                } else {
                    // EditText is empty
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter status message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        });

        /**
         * Button click event for logout from twitter
         * */
        btnLogoutTwitter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Call logout twitter function
                logoutFromTwitter();
            }
        });

        /**
         * Button click event for getting timeline from twitter *
         **/
        btnGetTimeLine.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // call getTimeLine function
                new getTimeLine().execute();
            }
        });

        /**
         * This if conditions is tested once is redirected from twitter page.
         * Parse the uri to get oAuth Verifier
         * */
        if (!isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
            Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
            if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL)) {
                // oAuth verifier
                String verifier = uri
                        .getQueryParameter(URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER);

                try {
                    // Get the access token
                    AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(
                            requestToken, verifier);

                    // Shared Preferences
                    Editor e = mSharedPreferences.edit();

                    // After getting access token, access token secret
                    // store them in application preferences
                    e.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, accessToken.getToken());
                    e.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET,
                            accessToken.getTokenSecret());
                    // Store login status - true
                    e.putBoolean(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN, true);
                    e.commit(); // save changes

                    Log.e("Twitter OAuth Token", "> " + accessToken.getToken());

                    // Hide login button
                    btnLoginTwitter.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    // Show Update Twitter
                    lblUpdate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    txtUpdate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    btnUpdateStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    btnGetTimeLine.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    btnLogoutTwitter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    // Getting user details from twitter
                    // For now i am getting his name only
                    long userID = accessToken.getUserId();
                    User user = twitter.showUser(userID);
                    String username = user.getName();

                    // Displaying in xml ui
                    lblUserName.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Welcome " + username
                            + "</b>"));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Check log for login errors
                    Log.e("Twitter Login Error", "> " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Function to login twitter
     * */
    private void loginToTwitter() {
        // Check if already logged in
        if (!isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
            ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
            builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
            Configuration configuration = builder.build();

            TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
            twitter = factory.getInstance();

            try {
                requestToken = twitter
                        .getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);
                this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                        .parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL())));
            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            // user already logged into twitter
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Already Logged into twitter", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Function to update status
     * */
    class updateTwitterStatus extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Updating to twitter...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting Places JSON
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            Log.d("Tweet Text", "> " + args[0]);
            String status = args[0];
            try {
                ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
                builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
                builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);

                // Access Token
                String access_token = mSharedPreferences.getString(
                        PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
                // Access Token Secret
                String access_token_secret = mSharedPreferences.getString(
                        PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET, "");

                AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(access_token,
                        access_token_secret);
                Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(builder.build())
                        .getInstance(accessToken);

                // Update status
                twitter4j.Status response = twitter.updateStatus(status);

                Log.d("Status", "> " + response.getText());
            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                // Error in updating status
                Log.d("Twitter Update Error", e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog and show
         * the data in UI Always use runOnUiThread(new Runnable()) to update UI
         * from background thread, otherwise you will get error
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Status tweeted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    // Clearing EditText field
                    txtUpdate.setText("");
                }
            });
        }

    }

    /**
     * Function to logout from twitter It will just clear the application shared
     * preferences
     * */
    private void logoutFromTwitter() {
        // Clear the shared preferences
        Editor e = mSharedPreferences.edit();
        e.remove(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN);
        e.remove(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET);
        e.remove(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN);
        e.commit();

        // After this take the appropriate action
        // I am showing the hiding/showing buttons again
        // You might not needed this code
        btnGetTimeLine.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnLogoutTwitter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnUpdateStatus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        txtUpdate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        lblUpdate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        lblUserName.setText("");
        lblUserName.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        btnLoginTwitter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    /**
     * Check user already logged in your application using twitter Login flag is
     * fetched from Shared Preferences
     * */
    private boolean isTwitterLoggedInAlready() {
        // return twitter login status from Shared Preferences
        return mSharedPreferences.getBoolean(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN, false);
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    /**
     * Function to get timeline
     * */
    class getTimeLine extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Getting Timeline from Twitter...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting Places JSON
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(Void... args) {

            try {
                ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
                builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
                builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);

                // Access Token
                String access_token = mSharedPreferences.getString(
                        PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
                // Access Token Secret
                String access_token_secret = mSharedPreferences.getString(
                        PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET, "");

                AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(access_token,
                        access_token_secret);
                Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(builder.build())
                        .getInstance(accessToken);


                //Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
                User user = twitter.verifyCredentials();
                List<twitter4j.Status> statuses = twitter.getHomeTimeline();
                System.out.println("Showing @" + user.getScreenName()
                        + "'s home timeline.");
                for (twitter4j.Status status : statuses) {
                    Log.d("Twitter","@" + status.getUser().getScreenName()
                            + " - " + status.getText());
                }

            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                // Error in updating status
                Log.d("Twitter Update Error", e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Retrieving TimeLine Done..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            });
        }

    }

}
```

If you have any doubts, you can probably refer this question and ask your doubts and experts at SO can answer your doubts.

Hope this helps!!!

Thanks...

---

Images:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I followed all the steps that you mentioned above. I used my own secret and consumer key. But I'm not able to login. Means i'm not able to make my app authorize using twitter. What can be the issue?

Comment: Can you explain in a bit more detail on what's happening? What are the steps you followed and where is it that you are facing the problem? I can be helpful if you can provide me this information. If you are looking for something, like just fetching tweets, you need not make the user login everytime. There is a "Application level authorization" you can look into.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I made it working. The actual problem was that I declared my Activity of singleInstance, and thats why it was not receiving the uri and ultimately was not able to login. I solved the authentication as well as tweeting and re-tweeting features. The only thing I bothered about is to finish the web browser which automatically opens when user logins the first time. I want to finish this browser activity. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Close the browser? When do you want to close the browser? After user logs in and comes back to the app? If so, I am not sure on how to do this from the app.

Comment: Yes, as soon as user successfully logged in, and user returns in its activity's screen, the browser window remains open. How to finish it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Question itself has the answer. I am adding this answer, just to close the question. Please check the question, for proper working code on how to integrate.